# Journey API Entry Source - EventDefinition Key not found - errorcode 10000

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, journeybuilder

I'm trying to fire one journey though API entry source but I get the error
{
    "message": "EventDefinitionKey 'APIEvent-43f63b4f-02f4-62d2-cc88-c433c5dc0a76' not found",
    "errorcode": 10000,
    "documentation": ""
}

POST /interaction/v1/events

Host: RestEndpoint.rest.marketingcloudapis.com

Authorization: Bearer

{
"ContactKey":"Contact_Key",

"EventDefinitionKey":"APIEvent-43f63b4f-02f4-62d2-cc88-c433c5dc0a76",

"Data": {
    "Contact Key":"Contact_Key",
    "Email Address":"email@email.com"
    }
}

This is my entry event:

[image]

Regarding the package, it includes API integration Server-to-Server with full scope with enable Integration with the BU where the journey is.

Regarding the Data Extension is a Sendable Data Extension with two fields, Contact Key and Email Address.

This seems permission issues but the package have full scope... Do I need to create any additional component in the package?

Comment: Are you passing account id in your token/Auth call?

Comment: I'm with EazyE here, seems like you might be getting a token which doesn't relate to that BU. The error message infers everything around permissions is ok, but that the event doesn't exist

Comment: Hi @EazyE, sorry for my late feedback. You are correct, I was missing the account information in the token request.

Comment: I supplied my comment as an answer that you can accept  @PedroLopes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using the [oAuth 2.0](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-app-development.meta/mc-app-development/access-token-s2s.htm) token you need to ensure you are passing the `account_id` parameter to ensure the call is executing in the correct MID. By default the token assumes the MID of the MID that installed package is created in, and this API key is not found within that MID